# remove double quotes for every occurance of specific name of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON which looks like

```
{
  "screens": [
    {
      "screenName": "PriceCodes",
      "gridOptionsModel": {
        "columnDefs": [
          {
            "headerName": "enddate",
            "field": "date",
            "editable": true,
            "cellEditorFramework": "BootstrapDatePickerComponent"
          },
          {
            "headerName": "INT",
            "field": "int",
            "editable": true,
            "cellEditorFramework": "NumericEditorComponent"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and for every occurance of namecellEditorFramework i want value of that name without double quotes as below:

```
{
  "screens": [
    {
      "screenName": "PriceCodes",
      "gridOptionsModel": {
        "columnDefs": [
          {
            "headerName": "enddate",
            "field": "date",
            "editable": true,
            "cellEditorFramework": BootstrapDatePickerComponent
          },
          {
            "headerName": "INT",
            "field": "int",
            "editable": true,
            "cellEditorFramework": NumericEditorComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

please help me get this result

Comment: quotes are part of JSONs format, asking to change them doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you removed the quotes it would no longer be valid JSON.

Comment: So you want to make a string into an Object reference? seems weird.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: OP is trying to build a form from JSON object

Comment: yes i need this. because NumericEditorComponent and  BootstrapDatePickerComponent are reference to ngx-bootsrap component which i am using to get date cell editor and numeric cell editor in ag-grid. with double quotes around these reference does not resolve to be reference and throwing an error as component factory not found

Comment: Rehydrate the object using JSON.parse and then re-assign references. JSON can't hold references.

Comment: i am using this result in ag-grid, so it is not a concern whether JSON can hold references or not .

Comment: i need this result using javascript